# TFS Performance issue after deploying server plugins

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am using TFS 2010 SP1 and I have created TFS Plugins using C# code.

That plugin will get the changes of the work item and update another database.

Everything is working fine but all the TFS User faces problem with low performance. I have increased the RAM of the server upto 8 GB but still no luck.

I have checked on tfs server performance and saw that suddenly w3wp.exe process uses all the memory and cpu usage is 100%. While Remote Debugging, I found that workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workitemId) uses more cpu.

When i Remove the plugin then TFS behaves normally with good performance.

I am not able to identify the issue.

So can any one help me to identify the issue ?

When i Remove the plugin then TFS behaves normally with good performance.

I am not able to identify the issue.

So can any one help me to identify the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WorkItemStore` will traverse all type of `WorkItem` from TFS. If you have a specific work item types and you want to perform operation on that only, you can put a condition in TFS Plugin itself to filter out the specific work item type. Ex. Task, Bug, Productbacklog etc.

This can help you to boost the performance of your TFS.

Comment: After remote debugging, I came to know that i was facing the same issue and i was able to resolve this issue. Thanks for your suggestion.